# How do you restore the file associations to the Photos app on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: file-association, windows-server-2012-r2

GIMP took some file associations (for example *.png) that I would like restored to the Photos app that I presume is the default on Windows Server 2012 R2. How do I restore these file associations? I can't find the location of this app.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. In the opened box enter:

```
control /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms
```

Note: you can find Default Programs in the Control Panel.

**Method 1**
Set your default programs -> [Select program in which you want to open file] -> Choose defaults for this program -> [Tick box near the extension you need] -> Save.
Note: Windows not always shows all programs in this list.

**Method 2**
Associate a file type or protocol with a program -> [Find extension you need] -> Change Program -> [Choose program you need. Use browse option if necessary].

Comment: Photos app is not listed in Method 1. What is the location of the Photo program if using Method 2? While this answer is good in general, I posted the question because I already tried both methods and failed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed you can't find app itself. I have Photos app in pop-up apps list everytime. Can you find it in Start menu? Have you tried to uninstall it from Start menu (right-click -> Uninstall) and then reinstall it?

Comment: My mistake, the OS is actually Windows Server 2012 R2, not Windows 8. I don't see the Photos app in the start menu, but this VM was built for me so maybe it was removed, I don't know. Maybe the Photos app is not default or included on Windows Server 2012 R2.